# How can I fix this priority-queue code?

Tags: java

My code is basically like an elevator using dynamic queues.  I want to imitate the way a elevator works using code. I set it up according to user input:

- How many floors are in the building?
- What floor the user is trying to reach?

After that, I check the numbers to make sure the floor number is in the range form 1 and number of floors.
I put the numbers in a queue and when another number is added, I put the initial number in a dynamic queue.

I want to print all the numbers out that are passed on the way to the destination floor and I'm stuck right here. I want to print out the queue so I can see if it is working but I don't know how. I have to implement dynamic queue. So there is no getting rid of it.

```
import java.util.*;

public class ElevatorsCopy {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner floors = new Scanner(System.in);

    int floorMax;
    int floorNum;
    int n = 0;
    String floorCount = " ";

    System.out.println("How many floors are in the buiding");
    floorMax = floors.nextInt();

    System.out.println("There are " + floorMax + " floors in this building");

    System.out.println("Which floor would you like to go to?");

    floorNum = floors.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Going to the " + floorNum + " floor.");

    Queue<Integer> destFloor = new LinkedList<Integer>();

    PriorityQueue<Integer> priorityFloor = new PriorityQueue<Integer>();

    for ( int i =0 ; i <= floorMax; i++)
    {
        destFloor.add(i);
        for(int j =0; j <= floorMax; j++)
        {
            if(j <= floorMax)
            {
                destFloor.add(j);
                priorityFloor.add(i);
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("That floor does not exist.");
            }
        }
    }       
  }
}
```

Comment: To print the contents of the queue: `priorityFloor.forEach(floor -> System.out.println(floor));`

Comment: @Jameson, as long as you are aware this doesn’t guarantee printing in any particular order.

Comment: I don’t understand the purpose of your two queues. You can print `destFloor` with just `System.out.println(destFloor)` since it has a reasonable `toString` method.

Comment: Your check `if(j <= floorMax)` is superfluous since the enclosing `for` loop already makes sure the condition is fulfillled.

Comment: @OleV.V. Huh, why's that? `.forEach()` is on `Iteratable` and should have the same order as `.iterator()`, no? I tried it here and it prints LIFO order: https://ideone.com/F4am1t

Comment: @Jameson, [The docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#iterator--) say: “The iterator does not return the elements in any particular order.” https://ideone.com/bzQ7IS Seems it was just a coincidence in your example the three elements came out in reverse insertion order.

Comment: Ok so i printed it and it doesn't do what i need it to do.  I want it to go up to the initial number entered from 1 and stop.  After that if another number is entered i want it to begin from the initial number entered and go either up or down to the second number and stop and continue working like that. Like an elevator. I feel like it can be done with loops but i have to incorporate Dynamic queue

Comment: As long as you haven’t properly explained what you *do* need those two queues to do, how could we help?